# Extract integers from string in Fortran

Tags: arrays, string, integer, fortran

I'm using Fortran 90. I have a string declared as `CHARACTER(20) :: Folds`, which is assigned its value from a command line argument that looks like `x:y:z` where x, y, and z are all integers. I then need to pick out the numbers out of that string and to assign them to appropriate variables. This is how I tried doing it:

```
 i=1
 do j=1, LEN_TRIM(folds)
    temp_fold=''
    if (folds(j).neqv.':') then
        temp_fold(j)=folds(j)
    elseif (i.eq.1) then
        read(temp_fold,*) FoldX    
        i=i+1
    elseif (i.eq.2) then
        read(temp_fold,*) FoldY 
        i=i+1
    else
        read(temp_fold,*) FoldZ 
    endif
 enddo
```

When I compile this I get errors:

unfolder.f90(222): error #6410: This name has not been declared as an array or a function.   [FOLDS]

[stud2@feynman vec2ascii]$     if (folds(j).neqv.':') then
syntax error near unexpected token `j'
[stud2@feynman vec2ascii]$ --------^

unfolder.f90(223): error #6410: This name has not been declared as an array or a function.   [TEMP_FOLD]

[stud2@feynman vec2ascii]$         temp_fold(j)=folds(j)

syntax error near unexpected token `j'

How can I extract those numbers?

Comment: May I suggest that you make the compiler output clearer, to benefit posterity?  I would have had a go at it, but it's better to get it exactly right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `index` intrinsic function to locate the position in the string of the first colon, say `i`.  Then use an internal read to read the integer `x`from the preceding sub-string: `read (string (1:i-1), *) x`.   Then apply this procedure to the sub-string starting at `i+1` to obtain `y`.  Repeat for `z`.

P.S.  Are your error messages from bash rather than a Fortran compiler?

Comment: They are from fortran compiler, when i copied to clip board it inserted bash in there.

Answer (score 1):

With `folds` a character variable, to access a substring one needs a `(.:.)`.  That is, to access the single character with index `j`: `folds(j:j)`.

Without this, the compiler thinks that `folds` must be either an array (which it isn't) or a function (which isn't what you want).  This is what is meant by:

> This name has not been declared as an array or a function.

But in terms of then solving your problem, I second the answer given by @M.S.B. as it is more elegant.  Further, with the loop as it is (with the `(j:j)` correction in both `folds` and `temp_fold`) you're relying on each x, y, and z being single digit integers.  This other answer is much more general.

Comment: Thanks, if i use (j:j) then my method works. I like MSB's method, save from those ifs and a loop.